# Safari Max-Height Constrain Image

Tags: css

I am trying to constrain an image that works in Chrome and Moz but Safari its not. Basically I am doing this:

```
.brewery_logo img{
        max-height:64px;
        width:auto;
        margin:0 auto;
        display:block;
    }
```

In Safari it is holding the max height but stretching the image width to its actual size. In the other browsers it sets the max height and sets the width proportionally. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Your style definition by itself works as you intended on Safari (6.0.5). If you haven't already, check the Web Inspector (command+option+I) to see which other style rules might be applied to the image, because almost every time I've had a style surprise, it's been from another style rule overriding the intended one due to a hierarchy issue:

- id selectors take precedence over class selectors, which take
  precedence over tag selectors
- inline styles take precedence over    style tags, which take
  precedence over external style sheets
- nested selectors take precedence over less nested selectors (e.g.
  body div img vs. body img)
- with duplicate definitions, the last declared will    take precedence